# How do I generate projectiles toward the mouse pointer?

Tags: xna, c#, mouse, control, trigonometry

I'm making a top-down space shooter where the player controls a ship and can aim and shoot using the mouse cursor. How can I fire bullets *from the ship* at the *angle from the ship to the mouse cursor*?

Comment: Is it that you need help calculating the angle based on the mouse cursor?

Comment: Yeah, sorry if my question is somewhat vague in that regard. And also how to move the projectile based on the angle, that too I need.

Comment: Wait, you're asking us about basic trigonometry, or the means to implement it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understood your problem properly, you just want to shoot a bullet towards a mouse position. Here is how I would do:

First of all, you must find the movement required for the bullet to get to the mouse, like so:

```
Vector2 movement = mousePosition - bulletStartPosition;
```

Then, you should normalize it to have a vector with a length of 1 so that you can hold a vector which tells you in which direction to go, like so:

```
movement.Normalize();
```

But here you have a little problem, if the direction is equal to `(0, 0)` (meaning that the mouse is on the bullet start position), then you'll divide by zero, so make sure you check for that with the last piece of code:

```
if (movement != Vector2.Zero)
    movement.Normalize();
```

So, you've got the movement required to move towards the mouse. You have to keep a `Vector2` within your bullet class which holds the `Direction` of the bullet.

What's next? You have to actually move the bullet!

In your bullet update code, do the following:

```
bullet.Position += bullet.Direction * bullet.Speed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds; // multiply by delta seconds to keep a consistent speed on all computers.
```

Where `bullet.Speed` is a float representing the bullet's speed in units per second.

Basically, here are the things to change:

Inside you bullet class, add a `float Speed` and a `Vector2 Direction`.

When shooting, set your `bullet.Direction` to `mousePosition - bullet.Position` and safely normalize it (by checking for equality with `Vector2.Zero` first).

When updating your bullet, do the following: `bullet.Position += bullet.Direction * bullet.Speed * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;`.

It should work.

Comment: +1 Vectors are a wonderful thing. [Learn them!](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/vector/info)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick ! Awesome link on the vectors too, definitely something I'll read soon.

Comment: what is movement used for after you normalize it? I dont see it being used.

Comment: @Raptrex: Actually movement is what I called the Direction later on. I just called it `movement` in the code to first show what it represents. It is basically just the Direction vector.

Comment: @JesseEmond Welcome to the vote to close privilege, use it wisely.

Answer (score 6):

If you're having trouble calculating the angle, you can use this:

```
Vector2 target = mousePos - startPos;
float angle = Math.Atan2( target.Y, target.X );
```